# Branch cut of $w=\left(\dfrac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^{1/3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

I'd like todetermine a branch cut for the function $w=\left(\dfrac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^{1/3}$ that allows to construct analytic branches defined on $|z|>1 \;,\; \forall z\in \mathbb C$. How can I do this?

I noticed: branch points are $z=1$ and $z=-1$. So I'd say: $[-1,1]$ is the branch cut needed. Is this correct?

Comment: [Quite related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/545249/).

Answer (score 3):

Note that the quotient $$\frac{z+1}{z-1} $$ is real and nonpositive only on the interval $[-1,1]$. Thus , it is possible to define an analytic branch of $$\log \left( \frac{z+1}{z-1} \right) $$ in $\mathbb C \setminus [-1,1]$ where the imaginary part lies in $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Then $$\exp \left( \frac{1}{3} \log \left(\frac{z+1}{z-1} \right) \right) $$ provides the desired analytic branch.

In short - you are right.

Comment: Why do you involve the log in this?

Comment: @Bob How do you define the complex powers $z^w$?

Comment: In this case I'd say: $w^3= \frac{z+1}{z-1}$. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Bob for any $z \neq -1$ there are three different possible candidates for $w$. Using a definite branch of the logarithm picks one.

Comment: Sorry but still don't get it. Should I for every function involve the log?

Comment: @Bob It's ok. Using the logarithm is convenient when dealing with powers, not in every case.

Comment: @Bob Think about $\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ as $g(z)$. The map $z\mapsto g(z)$ pops out $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ when you don't feed it any $z$'s from $|z|\leq 1$. In the next step you're going to be feeding $g(z)$'s into $\log()$, but none of the $g(z)$'s are from the non-positive real axis. Which branch cut of $\log$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ without the real non-positive axis?